# Windows service not Auto starting on powering up or reboot

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I have a windows service installed on my PC and I have another application which checks whether the service is running and only if the service is running does my application open up. And my issue here is every time my system restarts the service which is set to startup Automatic (Delayed Start) goes into Starting mode and remains in that state like forever and I then have to use the task manager to end the service task and then start the service and it works fine from there on. How do I fix this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check Windows Event Log for any service errors. Does your service depend on any other service prior to starting?  If so mark it in your service declaration.  Interesting how it runs afterwards

Comment: I did there's no error being logged that's what is funny.

Comment: Hmm. If you're not dependent on anything, try **Automatic (Delayed)** instead of **Automatic** (though not ideal)

Comment: @Micky I have it on Automatic (Delayed Start). I checked the Event logs just to be sure but there's no log from the service and I was logging actions in a table in SQL as well but then because the service is still in starting state there's no log there as well

Comment: Are you checking both the "Windows Logs > Application" and "Windows Logs > System" sections in the [Event Viewer](http://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/event-viewer-troubleshoot-windows-services/)?

Comment: What did the service's authors say when you reported the problem?

Comment: @CoreTech I am the author and I can't seem to find the problem. I have the service running fine on my system but my client machine is having this problem and I need to fix it